# Firefox style left hand bookmarks menu for chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Pressing ctrl + b in firefox opens a bookmarks toolbar, I'd like to move to chrome but this is holding me back.

Is the same functionality available in a chrome addon, searching hasn't yielded any results.

Comment: This extension provides a real sidebar in Chrome: https://github.com/niutech/chrome-devtools-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bring up the bookmarks toolbar, which can have folders.

You can also right click and go to the *Bookmark manager* for a full screen view, or put this in the nav bar: `chrome://bookmarks/#1`

There in fact are many extensions related to bookmarks, as can be seen on this search:

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/bookmark?hl=en-US

My personal recommendation (as I think bookmarks are so 1999) would be to use one of the read-later style services instead like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) or one of the many [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/instapaper/), but if you want to stick with the bookmark approach then the only thing lacking in default chrome is the side panel layout like Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Slimjet from http://www.slimjet.com. It is based on Chromium but comes with a native bookmarks side panel. [image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (is there a chrome addon to make ctrl + b open the bookmarks bar). This should probably be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this extension:
[TabsOutliner](http://tabsoutliner.com)

It is allows to save the tabs, and the saved tabs is in fact the complete analogy of bookmarks. Also it is possible to assign the keyboard shortcut to open its panel.

But in additional to manage saved tabs it also gives possibility to manage open ones, windows, saving the sessions, recovering after crashes, adding notes to tabs, and just looks cool:

[image]

Declaimer: I am its developer